# Needs help on actually making the trigonometric function work as intended

Tags: java, libgdx, geometry, trigonometry, kotlin

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch
import kotlin.math.*

class Player : Entity // Entity : Sprite
{
    var cursor : Sprite
    var cursorDistance : Float = 1f

    constructor(animationInfo:  HashMap<String, CustomAnimation>,
                initialX : Float =0f,
                initialY: Float = 0f) : super(animationInfo, initialX, initialY)
    {
        cursor = Sprite(Textures.idleArrow)
        cursor.setPosition(this.x, this.y)
//        cursor.setOriginCenter()
    }
    override fun updateLogic(delta: Float)
    {
        var degree = degreesToMouse(returnRadians = true)
        var curX = cursorDistance * cos(degree) + (x + getWorldOriginX)
        var curY = cursorDistance * sin(degree) + (y + getWorldOriginY)
        cursor.setPosition(curX, curY)
        cursor.setOriginCenter()
        cursor.rotation = degreesToMouse(cursor.x * TILE_WIDTH + cursor.originX,
            screenYPoint = cursor.y * TILE_HEIGHT + cursor.originY,
            returnRadians = false)
        println("cursor rotation: ${cursor.rotation}, degree: $degree")
    }

    override fun gameDraw(batch: SpriteBatch) {
        super.gameDraw(batch)
        batch.draw(
            cursor, cursor.x, cursor.y, cursor.originX / TILE_WIDTH, cursor.originY / TILE_WIDTH,
            (cursor.regionWidth / TILE_WIDTH.toFloat()), (cursor.regionHeight / TILE_HEIGHT.toFloat()),
            cursor.scaleX, cursor.scaleY, cursor.rotation)

    }
}
```

````
    fun degreesToMouse(arg: Entity = this, returnRadians: Boolean = false) : Float
    {
        var radians = atan2(
            Gdx.input.y.toDouble() - arg.screenPosition.y + arg.originY * arg.readOnlyScaling.y,
            Gdx.input.x.toDouble() - arg.screenPosition.x + arg.originX * arg.readOnlyScaling.x)
        if(!returnRadians)
            return  -(radians * (180 / Math.PI)).toFloat()
        else
            return radians.toFloat()
    }
    fun degreesToMouse(screenXPoint: Float, screenYPoint: Float, returnRadians: Boolean = false) : Float
    {
        var radians = atan2(
            Gdx.input.y.toDouble() - screenYPoint,
            Gdx.input.x.toDouble() - screenYPoint)
        if(!returnRadians)
            return  -(radians * (180 / Math.PI)).toFloat()
        else
            return radians.toFloat()
    }```
````

this is all the related code, the only important place is the updateLogic function, thanks to help of some people, i got that `cos(degree)` `sin(degree)` etc. however currently it doesn't work at all like i intended, i intended for it to work like this:

[image]

but currently it is like this:
[image]

as you can see, nor does the arrow look at the mouse cursor, nor would the line and the point at the ring interact if a line was drawn between center and mouse, I need a  bit of help on that part. There are a lot of conversions and divisions like TILE_WIDTH etc. those are there because I need to use a `FitViewport` and a Tile Renderer, Tilewidth and TileHeight are 32, and those need conversion

Comment: It looks like you just need to negate the y value you're getting from the sine function, because your vertical axis is upside down relative to what your code expects.

Comment: the problem is that if i do that, like, if the player goes down, the arrow goes up and vice versa

Comment: Sounds like you're negating the player position too, instead of just the offset you get from the sine function as I described.

Comment: i guess i will do cursorDistance - calculated value?

Comment: @DMGregory i did the following in the answers according to your comment and it works, thanks. Though there is one problem left and its that the cursor doesnt "look at" the mouse, if you could help that too, i would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

thanks to the help of @DMGregory and the people who helped me initially make this code, found the answer to make that cursor thing orbit around the player according to the position to the mouse:

```
        var degree = degreesToMouse(returnRadians = true)
        var curX = (cursorDistance * cos(degree)) + (x + getWorldOriginX)
        var curY = (cursorDistance - (cursorDistance * sin(degree))) + (y + getWorldOriginY) - 1
        cursor.setPosition(curX, curY)
```

`cursorDistance` is the obvious variable, `x` is in the viewport units so it doesnt get conversion, `getWorldOriginX` and `getWorldOriginY` returns originX-Y / TILE_WIDTH-HEIGHT as those arent initially in world units but pixel units as it is based of the texture, and to make that arrow point towards the cursor i did:

```
cursor.rotation = degreesToMouse() + 270
```

Comment: I think you want `a = degree` (or some variant on it like negating it or shifting it by 90 or 180, depending on your coordinate system). `(curX, curY)` is an arrow pointing to the cursor from the scene origin, not from the center of the player sprite, so it does not correspond to the direction you want the cursor to point.

Comment: I did `cursor.rotation = degreesToMouse() + 270` and it all works fine, thanks so much

Comment: @DMGregory also what would you suggest naming the title as? I didn't even know what to search for while making this, some people helped me, but I still don't know what this would be called

Comment: [The unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)? [Bearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(angle))?